# Poisson GLM with categorical data

Tags: r, rstudio, glm, poisson

I'm trying to fit a Poisson generalized mixed model using counts of categorical data labeled as `s` and `v`. Since the data was collected within sessions that have a different duration (see `session_dur_s`), I want to include this information as a predictor by putting `offset` in the glm model.

Here is my table:

```
label session counts session_dur_s
s   1   587 6843    
s   2   203 2095    
s   3   187 1834    
s   4   122 1340    
s   5   40  1108    
s   6   64  476 
s   7   60  593 
v   1   147 6721    
v   2   57  2095    
v   3   58  1834    
v   4   22  986 
v   5   8   1108    
v   6   12  476 
v   7   11  593
```

My data:

```
label <-   c("s","s","s","s","s","s","s","v","v","v","v","v","v","v")
session <-  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
counts <- c(587,203,187,122,40,64,60,147,54,58,22,8,12,11)
session_dur_s <-c(6843,2095,1834,1340,1108,476,593,6721,2095,1834,986,1108,476,593)
sv_dur <-  data.frame(label,session,counts,session_dur_s)
```

That's my code:

```
sv_dur_mod <- glm(counts ~ label * session, data=sv_dur, family = "poisson",offset =session_dur_s)

summary(sv_dur_mod)

plot(allEffects(sv_dur_mod),type="response")
```

I can't execute the glm function because I receive the beautiful error:

`Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values`

I'm not sure how to go about it. I would be really happy if a smart head could point me what can I do in order to work it out.

If there is a better model that I can use to predict the counts over time for the both `s` and `v` labels, I'm more than open to go for it.

Many thanks for comments and suggestions!

P.S. I'm running it in the R markdown script using following packages `tidyverse`, `effects` and `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

A Poisson GLM uses a log link as default. That is, it can executed as:

```
sv_dur_mod <- glm(counts ~ label * session,
                  data = sv_dur,
                  family = poisson("log"))
```

Accordingly, a log offset is generally appropriate:

```
sv_dur_mod <- glm(counts ~ label * session,
                  data = sv_dur,
                  offset = log(session_dur_s),
                  family = poisson("log"))
```

Which executes as expected. See the answer here for more information on using a log offset: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237980/70372

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll for sure have a look at the log offset. Now, just out of curiosity. If I would like to use the `dur_s` instead of `counts` in my model, I would have to use log(dur_s) or not?